# Another poorly bay tree

Tags: trees, herbs

I don't believe any of the previous sick bay tree questions have shown the same symptoms: large brown patches on some leaves.

[image: Bay with brown patches on leaves]

It's one of two  standard bays I've got by the front door, both in pots of about 20-30 l.  We're having a heatwave here (by British standards, i.e. getting up to about 30°C, <2 mm of rain in the last 6 weeks) but I've been watering the compost fairly generously every couple of days and I'd expect drought to cause a more general drying without the new growth.  The other is healthy and has similar amounts of new growth. Both get the afternoon/evening sun, but are in shade for the hottest part of the day.

I potted them up last year into home-made compost, which I've found successful for other long-term pot plants including the kitchen-garden bay several years older. Besides I try to avoid using too much bought-in compost for  environmental reasons (most of what I can buy without a special trip is based on peat). I don't usually pick the leaves off this one as I have another closer to the kitchen, so any treatment doesn't have to be suitable for crops.

So I'd like to know what's wrong, what to do about it, and especially whether it's like to spread to the other tree a metre or so away.

Comment: It looks suspiciously like a mechanical 'burn'.  What happened about 2 months or so ago?  Was anything sprayed in the vicinity of this shrub?

Comment: @stormy, interesting. I'm very sparing with garden chemicals and haven't used any near there for years (except plant food with a watering can), and I don't think anyone else can have done within say 15m. No DIY chemicals either in that area, and while vehicle exhaust gets reasonably close there are other plants in between undamaged. Most of the damage is on one side, but there is a little on the top on the opposite side. On that basis I'm thinking I should snip off the affected leaves carefully and monitor.

Comment: This looks like heat scorch to me. I did a similar thing a few months ago when I burnt some papers outside and the heat got too close to a pot. With the current weather and wall proximity, I’d say it’s that. Nothing to worry about, plant will recover

Comment: @ChrisH  Go ahead and snip off the damaged leaves.  It costs the plant more to repair those leaves than the leaves can provide in carbs to account for their own keep.  What kind of plant 'food' do you use when you water?  I hate to be a butt but plants make their own food, fertilizer, compost...none of that is food for plants.  The 'word' nutrients is just wrong.  Plants have to have specific chemistry to be healthy, vigorous and produce food for us humans.  Does not come from compost, the air, the water, the soil.  It HAS to be added and very carefully. It would be nice to know what happened.

Comment: @stormy thanks, I don't feed slow growing things very much, but they get some worm juice early in the season, and a little tomato/fruit liquid fertiliser when I'm using it on something nearby. I'd rather under feed in pots and address any problems, then have lots of runoff or saturate the compost with excess nutrients (note UK usage: "potting compost" = "potting soil"). I can't think of a cause for heat or chemical burns, let alone one that wouldn't affect the other one

Comment: What the heck is worm juice?  Grins!  When I see a plant that has damage on one side (mostly) and the rest of the plant is hunkydory, that tells me mechanical damage.  When the leaf is the proper color excepting a big burnt spot...mechanical damage.  Arghhh. 'Potting Compost' for 'Potting soil'...was this compost decomposed or raw?  Main thing is was it sterilized?  I am very very glad you don't over FEED your plants.  I would imagine worm juice is not a balanced fertilizer.  Plants need a basic balanced NPK.  Sterilized potting MEDIUM'.  I agree, a little now and watch for the results!

Comment: Worm juice is the liquid from a vermicomposter. Quite good for N and micronutrients (used more concentrated than commercial plant food). P and K depend on what you put in so better for foliage plants and early season feeding than for fruiting plants (@stormy)

Comment: Also @stormy "potting compost" is the name given to bought, sterilised mixes as well as mixes based on decomposed plant matter made at home. Mine tends to be well (if slowly) decomposed and is generally very successful for potting on all but the most demanding plants

Comment: Yeah, I have major problems with definitions of terms.  Potting soil normally is made with little to no 'real' soil particles.  Coir, vermiculite, pearlite, peat...organic stuff that is neutral, not broken down.  Sterilized with heat.  This makes a MEDIUM for plants having to be planted in pots.  Just like hydroponics where water is a medium.  Planting in the larger body of garden soil it is necessary to know the ecology, biology, soils...drainage because the only strategy is to work with nature.  Ugh that word nature.  Natural.  Organic.  There are as many definitions as people who interpret.